# MySql to Python Model Creation Tool

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to migrate a site written in PHP/MySQL to a Python/Django.  There  will be some significant modifications to the application, but I am not expecting any significant changes to the backend persistence.

Essentially I would like to find a tool that will create the

```
django.db.models.Model
```

classes for me. For example consider:

```
create table blah (
   a varchar(10) not null 
   , b varchar(10) not null 
)
```

and I run the tool and it generates the following models.py file for me

```
class Blah(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Something I can run command line OR wherever.  Thanks, and I am new to python/django so I apologize if there is well known solution (although google isn't showing me one).

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django can handle it, see [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) management command:

> Introspects the database tables in the database pointed-to by the NAME
>   setting and outputs a Django model module (a models.py file) to
>   standard output.

Also, consider using [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for further schema and data migrations.